# Compiling sequence

Tags: compilation, sequence

I'm curious to know how the java compiler compiles a code, ie., the sequence in which it compiles. Does it go through the code top to bottom like one reads a story or does it begin with the main method.

Say, it goes to main, creates whatever object the main method following the fields declared before the object creation. Then, goes to the class the object name refers; and in that class (if it is another .java file), what sequence does the compilation follow? Pl let me know.

How does it work with two-three or more classes including a main class as separate java files?

Comment: _"Say, it goes to main, creates whatever object the main method"_ The compiler doesn't _run_ your code.

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't use the right word. What I meant was, how does the code get read when you run it, the sequence, I mean. And, if there are two or three more classes as separate java files including a main class, what is the sequence?